# Regex pattern for matching special characters in url

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match url  in javascript using `match()` function, It takes regex as a pattern. I need to match special characters of url ( `://..:/.?=&` )

```
var url = 'http://www.sun.com:80/index.html?q=1&q2=2#fragment';
```

I have checked other pages but unable to find specific regex.
and please also suggest good source to learn about writing regex.

[Update]
I am trying to break url in strings save into the array like (`string= ['http', '', '', 'www', 'sun', 'com', '80', 'index', 'html', 'q', '1', 'q2', '2']`) . For example - if pattern matches a variable saves the index position of url and then i use `slice()` function to extract the value ,my working url might be on different languages also (urdu etc) , i need to write regex for specific url symbols (:/.?=&# )

Comment: This will be helpful - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: If you explain what you expect from the url, will let you the correct pattern for it.

Comment: now, added updated one. check the answer again. (The first one will suit for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest one (works for any language), since we added only the special characters here.

```
decodeURI(window.location.href).split(/[\/.?=&:#]+/g);
```

The following is for English:-

```
   var res = window.location.href.split(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g);
```

res will be the result array containing all text(param and values) except the special characters. There are better ways to parse the URL, but that depends on what is required. This solution is for what you exactly asked for.
If URL contains Urdu characters:-

```
decodeURI(window.location.href).split(/[^A-Za-z0-9\u0600-\u06ff]+/g);
```

\u0600-\u6ff -> this is the unicode range of URDU characters. Now added that too. Note, we added "decodeURI", so that first the non-english characters will get decoded and then we do the search using regex.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for. I guess my way of doing with if condition,match() function is long and slow. Need to learn more javascript :D .

Comment: this solution wont work , as the my working url might be on different languages also (urdu etc) , i need to write regex for specific url symbols (://..:/.?=& )

Comment: oh! so you need to add up the unicode for those characters in this regex.

Comment: can u give an example URL?

Comment: adding unicode wont work in my opinion because characters in other languages are too many ,It is not possible to unicode every character. I need to write regex for specific characters (:/.?=&#) . OR i go to classic programming , Save this pattern in different array and run two loops to match every character with pattern, then slice the value.  What do you suggest to do this task.

Comment: decodeURI(window.location.href).split(/[\/.?=&:#]+/g);
This works on all language , Thanks.